# Django - Get the first and last names of an user

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

When a user is created, one can add the first and last name in the user's profile.

My question is: how can I access this information? If I only wanted the username I would do it with `user.get_username`. How should I access first name and last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**`User`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) object has a [**`.first_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.first_name) and [**`.last_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_name) attribute as well.

So for a user `u`, you can fetch:

```
the_first_name = u.first_name
the_last_name = u.last_name
```

Note that both can empty, and these are not required to be unique.

You can also access what Django defines as the "full name" with [**`.get_full_name()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_full_name). In that case Django joins the `.first_name` and the `.last_name` together, with a space in the middle.

In fact these fields and functions are defined in the [**`AbstractUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) model, as you can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L288). In case you customize the user model, it is possible that those fields no longer exist.